# Application that links anonymously written text to an identity

Tags: data-analysis, anonymization

I just wondered whether there is a tool, which can link anonymously written text to an identity.
Like a tool that could be trained with some data and would - by analyzing grammar, words, punctuation and so on, guess who the author was.

Like for example, a tool that can discover multi-accounts in a bulletin board by text-analysis.

Anybody got an idea?